# clean video glitches once imported into after effects

Tags: video, adobe, after-effects, video-editing, montage

So I edited a video in premiere pro and I now want to add some effects in after effects.
It mostly works well, but sometimes, there is a small glitch at a random place in the video that I important and I don't know why since the source video does not have any glitches.

Can someone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is rare, but this can happen since AE does not have the same import modules as Premiere. I've seen cases when AE would not read properly some mp4 files, and Premiere could read them nicely.

How are you importing in AE ? Do you import the Premiere Pro project and have the entire timeline recreated? This means that AE will import the same video sources as Premiere. If AE has an issue with this specific format, that might be the issue.

A workaround would be to render out your video in Premiere Pro, and then import this video in AE. You can use a lossless output format, but something like ProRes422HQ will most likely do the job without taking too much disk space. It is also a format that AE will surely understand.

In short, the safe bet is to "bake" what you see correctly in Premiere Pro by rendering your timeline, then importing this render in AE, rather than the original sources.

Comment: Thank you! I manage to resolve my problem with this technique: https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/footage-glitch-in-both-after-effects-and-premiere/td-p/10317417 , but still, the infos you gave me will be helpful for the future